# PowerBI Web app Dashboard Sample error AADSTS50011

Tags: visual-studio, azure, powerbi

I download the integrate-dashboard-web-app and enter the ClientSecret and the ClientID values in the cloud.config file. But when I run the project I am getting this error "AADSTS50011: The reply address 'http://localhost:13526/Redirect' does not match the reply addresses". Is there some additaional setting I need to add to the Azure Active Directory? I dont see anything that related to the application for power BI in Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error. Below is how I fixed it:

1. Ensure that the `Redirect URL` set on the Power BI App (registered) is http://localhost:13526/Redirect
2. In the sample app, ensure the Cloud.config `RedirectUrl` setting has the value http://localhost:13526/Redirect
3. In the sample app, in the Page_Load method in redirect.aspx.cs, change the line:

   `string redirectUri = String.Format("{0}Redirect", Properties.Settings.Default.RedirectUrl);`

   to:

   `string redirectUri = String.Format("{0}", Properties.Settings.Default.RedirectUrl);`